# Trouble trying to find length of longest substring

Tags: python, substring

I wrote the following code. It should return to me the length of the longest subscript in a string without a repeat in letters.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    lst = []
    y = 0
    final = 0
    count = len(s)      
    while len(s) > 0:
        s = s[y:]            
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in lst:
                y += 1
                count = len(lst)
                lst =[]
                break
            else:
                lst.append(s[i])

        if count > final:
            final=count 
    return(final)
```

when entering the string "tmmzuxt" i expect to get an output of 5 (length of "mzuxt") but instead get 4. I have debugged to figure out the problem seems to be that my function skips over the second 'm' when indexing but I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

Realized I somehow missed a line. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: where is final updated?  this will always return 0

Comment: are you sure you posted the correct code? At the second last line you start an if statement, without using it, which throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you incremented y, even though it should only ever remove the first character. There is no need for a variable y. Try this:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    final = 0
    while len(s) > 0:
        count = len(s)
        lst = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in lst:
                count = i - 1
                break
            lst.append(s[i])
        if count > final:
            final = count
        s = s[1:]
    return final

print(lengthOfLongestSubstring("tmmzuxt"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that you are modifying `s` while you are running your code.
Consider that in the first iteration, you are getting `s = s[0:]`, so `s` will now be `'tmmzuxt'`. In your next iteration, you are getting `s = s[1:]`, from the modified `s`. This is still not a problem, because you just get `'mmzuxt'`. However, in your third iteration, you are getting `s = s[2:]`, which is now `'zuxt'`.
So you need a different variable than `s` to hold the substring of `s` that you are actually testing.

Comment: This explanation makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

here, in your code(line 7) you are updating your string value inside function, everytime your for loop iterates.
for e.g., after every break inside for loop. you string(which is "tmmzuxt") is becoming short and short.

i created a new variable which contains your original string.

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    lst = []
    y = 0
    final = 0
    count = len(s)
    main_string = s;#change done here
    while len(s) > 0:
        
        s = main_string[y:] #change done here
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in lst:
                y += 1
                count = len(lst)
                lst =[]
                break
            else:
                lst.append(s[i])
            
        if count > final: 
            final =count
            print(final)
    return(final)

lengthOfLongestSubstring("tmmzuxt")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your code, or if the `while` loop is needed here, actually. Try this instead:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    max_length = 0
    length = 0
    previous = ''
    for thisCharacter in s:
        if thisCharacter != previous:
            length += 1
        else:
            max_length = max(length, max_length)
            length = 1
    return max_length
```

Comment: There is no `return` statement in your function

Comment: oops i forgot to add in at the end

Comment: Nevermind this just returns the number of characters in the string

Comment: facepalm let me fix that

Comment: This still returns the number of chracters in the string

Answer (score 1):

Here is an edited code. removing #`lst =[]` and  #`break` lines.

[**Code**]

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    lst = []
    y = 0
    final = 0
    count = len(s)      
    while len(s) > 0:
        s = s[y:]            
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in lst:
                y += 1
                count = len(lst)
                #lst =[]
                #break
            else:
                lst.append(s[i])

        if count > final:
            final=count 
    return(final)

s="tmmzuxt"
print(lengthOfLongestSubstring(s))
```

[**Output**]

```
5
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @FH_Mad_SWF This does not do what you asked for, this simply counts the number of unique character in the string